# Accidentally deleted Android Sdk and i don't find how to download it again (Linux)

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, sdk

I tried to reinstall Android Studio on Ubuntu and seems not to get to download the Sdk this time.

Comment: In Android Studio you can set the location of it. Just downlod it and set it on Android Studio accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

**Go to** [Android Studio download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) and go to **`Get just the command line tools`** section and download the SDK tools for `Linux`

**Then** after download is done, launch the `SDK manger` and install the needed packages.

**Then finally**, Open Android studio and change the `SDK` path to your new path, see attached screenshot for this step

[image]

Comment: So what I ended up doing was downloading Android Studio, and restoring the SDKs into their default folder then doing a copy paste to the one used by visual studio, if you just use Visual Studio as the destination it fails for some reason... perhaps wont happen to everyone just saying my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue and resolved with below steps. It could be bit similar to the above solution, but those steps need to be corrected with proper screenshots

1. Download `Android Studio` for any OS https://developer.android.com/studio
2. Install the exe for windows / ./studio.sh file for linux
3. Since you have deleted the `Android SDK` folder, it won't show the `Setup Wizard`, no worries. Go to next step
4. Follow the steps and refer the screenshots below
5. `Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> Edit -> Select the Android SDK`
   [image]
   [image]
6. Once you install this, `Android SDK` files would be created, but not the `tools` directory
7. To get the `tools` directory inside SDK folder, follow below steps
   `Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager`
   `Android SDK -> SDK tools`
   Uncheck `Hide obsolete packages` checkbox
   Select `Android SDK tools (obsolete)` checkbox
   Click `Ok` button and complete the installation and check the android folder

Now the `Android SDK` folders and files will be created including `tools` folder
[image]

[image]